# Issue with Querying Large Table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Started having the following errors as the size of my database grow. It's at about 4GB now for this table with millions of rows.

Laravel cant handle large tables?

```
$count = DB::table('table1')->distinct('data')->count(["data"]);
$count2 = DB::table('table2')->distinct('data')->count(["data"]);
```

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active. Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll(). Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute. (SQL: select count(distinct `data`) as aggregate from `data`)

Answer (score 0):

I think the table is very large and will take some time to finish. You are running another huge query directly after which also needs a long time to fully execute. I think you need to rerun a second query when first finishes.

Please try this:

```
$count = DB::table('table1')->distinct('data')->count(["data"]);
if($count){
$count2 = DB::table('table2')->distinct('data')->count(["data"]);
}
```

But this will need a result from first the query.

Try using:

`if($count>-1)`

or

```
 if(DB::table('table1')->distinct('data')->count(["data"]) >-1){
    $count2 = DB::table('table2')->distinct('data')->count(["data"]);
}
```

For the MySQL statement this might be faster:

```
DB::table('table1')->select(DB::raw("SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT data)"))->count();
```

And best solution will be using execute as Laravel allow to use it too

Please tell me if you encounter any problems.